# cocos2d-x and box2d linking error

Tags: c++, cocos2d-x, unresolved-external, cocos2d-x-3.0

I have troubles working in `cocos2d-x v3`. Actually, I want to init `box2d world object`.
I have created my game project properly, as it was given in `cocos2d-x` manual.
Now what's the trouble:

```
b2Vec2 gravity = b2Vec2(0.0f, -10.0f);
b2World world(gravity);
```

In this code the second line gives the compiler

```
'unresolved external symbol error':(
```

Without instantinating `b2World` object, everything compiles and works fine.

Have anybody faced this problem?

Comment: that 2nd line doesn't look like correct c++ (missing 'new', result not assigned to a variable) .. did you omit something? Ought to be like: b2World* world = new b2World(gravity); but world also ought to be a member var.

Comment: I tried to do both variants. But still no of them works, and I am getting linking error. Header "Box2D\Box2D.h" I also included.

Comment: @LearnCocos2D, Did you actually know that there are 2 types of initializating and assigning variables in C++? You just told me to create variable on the heap, while I was creating it on the stack. The problem is not in this, the problem is some kind of linking.

Comment: You need the world on the heap so i didn't consider this. Also my c++ is rusty. ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a very common linker error in Visual Studio and you have to add `libbox2d.lib` in your project properties.

`Right Click Project -> Project Properties -> Linker -> Input -> Additional Dependencies`

Now edit and add `libbox2d.lib` at the end and run project again.

Comment: where can I find libbox2d.lib? I added this as extra dependency, so this is my dependency listin Input->AdditionalDependencies: libbox2d.lib;%(AdditionalDependencies)
Now when I try to compile, I receive LNK1104 error: can't open file libbox2d.lib.
p.s. I am using cocos2d-x 3.0rc1

Comment: You have to add `libBox2D` project to your solution. After adding, compile it, lib file will be build automatically. After that run your project. You can take example of TestCpp project in samples.